# how do you create charts using highcharts javascript library

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use highcharts to build a charts. I have the below code:

my data.json file looks like this:

```
{"DATETIME":[1369540800,1369541700,1369542600,1369543500,1369544400,1369545300,1369546200,1369547100,1369548000,1369548900],"CPU":[14.84,13.6333333333333,14.7666666666667,13.5333333333333,17.8666666666667,15.9333333333333,14.2333333333333,13.3,10.8333333333333,9.76666666666667]}
```

HIGHTCHARTS

```
            <style>

                    body
                    {
                            font: 10px arial;
                    }

            </style>

         <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function () {
                $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

                        $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                                type: 'line'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'CPU UTILIZATION'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                categories: ['Date']
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: '% CPU Utilization'
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{

                            data: data,
                            }]

                        });
                    });
                });


            </script>


    </head>

    <body>
           <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </body>
```

I dont see any values, dada.json file is in the same directory as index.html file. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is the question mark at the end of your chart function call?

Comment: @wergerl, that was it, fast finger. thank you.

Comment: @wergeld, I have a local json file that I would like to chart that. How I would do that here, instead of manually inputing the series data?

Comment: Without knowing your json set up I cannot give specifics. But, take a look at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should have data name instead of datetime. Morever I see only dates, not y values.

"DATETIME":

should be

"data":

Comment: My axis will be dates and yaxis will be cpu. I'm very new to this. Giving the above json file, how can I implement this. I can change the headers in the json file to anything.